# Priorizing CSS properties

Tags: css, dom

---

I am building websites for a while, and I have a question about CSS I can't really rid over. So there is that frequent situation when multiple classes affect a DOM element, and both classes declare the same properties. **For example:**

```
.first {
    color:white;
}

.second {
    color:black;
}
```

I know that if I have an element with `class="first second"` in that the text will be black. If I rather want it to be white, **I have several options:**

1. Using `!important`: I know this one is handy and I use it, but sometimes, if I use it too often, my CSS may become messy. I mean, multiple !important's can result the same basic situation.
2. Reordering the classes inline: if I am correct, which class comes first, it will be the priority one. This is nice, but i often work with environments where I can't affect that. Secondly, this is not a global but a local solution.
3. Reorder the CSS itself: well, this sounds interesting, but if I work with many stylesheets (and I do), it is hard to track, especially when it is WIP.

Actually what I am looking for is some workaround like `z-index` but for priorizing which class is stronger. Because I can't really find anything useful in this topic, I am just curious maybe it is a user error, and you guys know something I don't. How do you manage this? What do you suggest?

Comment: Reorder the CSS, or [make one selector more specific](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) than the other.

Comment: If you make the selection more specific then that will give it precedence. Like p.second takes precedence over .second

Comment: Good point. On the other hand this solution make it hard to access for other classes if it is needed later.

Answer (score 1):

`class="first second"` is the same as `class="second first"`. The priority is based on the **position of the declarations in your css** and not in their position on the html element.

So, if you want priority of a class against another, put the top priority class LAST on the css file.

```
.first {
color:white;
}
.second {
color:black;
}
```

in this example, class `second` has always priority over class `first`. This happens because browser scans through the css top-to-bottom and always applying the rules of matched classes that finds. So, the last matched class has priority over the previous matched classes.

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5c29dzrr/

Comment: You're right. Reordering my stylesheets is not a fancy workaround for me though.

Answer (score 1):

At the same specificity level, the CSS selector that is *furthest down the stylesheet* will be applied. So in your example, if you wanted in that situation to have the element with the white colour you would have to order your properties like so:

```
.second {
    color: black;
}

.first {
    color: white;
}
```

The order of the classes in the HTML tag is not important; it is the order in which they appear in your CSS.

The better way to handle this is to go with some better naming convention such as [BEM](http://bem.info/) or [SMACSS](https://smacss.com/) so that you don't have the issue of conflicting class names.

Edit: It might be worth reading up on specificity and the cascade for a better understanding of this. I found [this calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/) to be pretty handy in determining which rules will take precendence, although these days you can just use the developer tools to find out that information.

Comment: Thanks! BEM looks worthy to consider. I didn't know such thing exists.